Are there any links between Moses killing the Egyptian and striking the rock?
Is there any connection in the text between
Exodus 2:11-12

11 One day, after Moses had grown up, he went out to where his own
people were and watched them at their hard labor. He saw an Egyptian
beating a Hebrew, one of his own people. 12 Looking this way and that
and seeing no one, he killed the Egyptian and hid him in the sand.

and Numbers 20:10-11

10 He and Aaron gathered the assembly together in front of the rock and Moses said to them, “Listen, you rebels, must we bring you water out of this rock?” 11 Then Moses raised his arm and struck the rock twice with his staff. Water gushed out, and the community and their livestock drank.

I am asking because of a comment on this tweet about the Bible not condemning the killing the Egyptian. One pushback is that the striking of the rock is a continuation of Moses' sin nature as revealed in the killing of the Egyptian. Is there anything in the text that would make us think that the author is making a link between these two violent acts of Moses?

There is no literary link (no common words) - any link is a matter of opinion.

And as for Biblical condemnation, a good writing doesn't always need to be explicit. The narrator tells a story of Moses committing a murder out of anger, and the next thing you know he faces the consequence of 40 years of exile in the desert. I think it's pretty obvious what the writer (and by implication God) thinks of that. (The story also shows God's grace at work in restoring him from the desert to a place of leading God's people. But I guess that's another story.)

@ Peter Kirkpatrick - Speaking of God's grace, Moses did make it to the Promised Land! He set his foot down on the Mount of Transfiguration with Elijah when Jesus's episode of "transfiguration" occurred! By then, his angry temperament was changed, we can imagine.

Link of Events?Several events in Moses's life may be considered "linked" because they all relate to the character of Moses. While all people have a fallen nature, that predicament of fallenness manifests itself in various ways.
Moses's fatal flaw in his nature was a disposition to be angry in stressful  predicaments And his anger got the best of him in the end. (1) When he saw a fellow Israelite being mistreated, he got riled up, and went over-board in his response to the situation. He killed the Egyptian.(Exodus 2:11-12)
(2) When the congregation of Israelites engaged in golden calf worship he over-reacted by breaking the Ten Commandment Tablets in violent anger! He then had to return to the mountain and receive another copy.
(3) When the Israelites grumbled and complained about a lack of water, again Moses "blew up" and spoke ill-advisably., attacking the holiness of God. (Numbers 20:10-11)
In order for the Congregation of Israel to conquer and occupy the land of milk and honey there had to be a level-headed leader. Moses was not it. Joshua took over successfully.
There was no intentional linkage in the narration's composition methodology or grammar. The whole biography of the Exodus's leader, Moses, is simply an expose' of one man's struggle with human nature.

Marty Solomon (BEMA episode 30) notes that the Hebrew language has imagery in the passage of Num 20:10-11 that indicates Moses not only struck the rock but struck people as well in his frustration (likely killing them). This occurred at the the time his sister had passed and it looks like there was no ceremony for her yet the people complained to Moses and had no compassion for his loss. It looks very similar to the scene back in Egypt (Moses deals with injustice by killing and covering up - perhaps learning this from how Pharoah dealt with issues?) and God's response possibly had more to do with not wanting the values/culture of Egypt (the world) in the new kingdom he was trying to establish.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I can't speak of the author's intent, but both cases represent a providential opportunity gone wrong, in which Moses and the Israelites together might have established a foundation of faith to enter the promised land. In both cases, Moses' temper got the best of him and the people were unable to unite in hope under his leadership.
The first case is less obvious than the second, because Moses had not yet emerged as Israel's leader. However, we know from the story of the patriarch Joseph that it was possible for a Hebrew prophet to rise quickly to a position of penultimate power in Egypt. If Moses had shown his zeal to protect the Israelite without killing the taskmaster, his reputation as a pro-Israelite reformer would quickly spread. On that basis his 40 period of exile in Midian would have been unnecessary. As a new Joseph, he would  have been able to win the Pharaoh's support for Israel to leave Egypt 40 years earlier. However because he had killed the Egyptian rather than justly defending the Israelite slave, the people feared him; the Pharaoh sought his life; and he had to flee.
The second case has stronger biblical support. God wanted Moses to sanctify the rock and bring water forth for the people to drink. This was at the end of the 40-year course of wandering in the wilderness and the beginning of the period of conquest. Had Moses controlled his temper, he would have acted as God's agent to give the people hope and sustenance to enter Canaan. Instead, he sinned against God, the people remained in despair, and Joshua was chosen to replace Moses as Israel's leader. Only after another 40 year period did they successfully cross over into Canaan and establish themselves in the Promised Land.
Conclusion: There is indeed a connection between Moses killing the Egyptian and his striking the rock. Both came at the end of a 40 year period and he beginning of what might have been a new victorious course. Both involved Moses' uncontrolled anger, perhaps righteous at first but not truly representing God. Both were moments of potential hope for the Israelites, which instead became occasions of a sin that resulted in 40 more years of suffering.

@ Dan Fefferman - Don't forget the third incident where Moses exposed his "fallen human nature": Smashing the Ten Commandments tablets!  His battle with "human nature" was laid bare in the Torah...ours will be laid bare on Judgment Day, eh? (Hebrews 4:13, 16)

Both were sinful but there isn’t a literary link between the two. God punishes Moses by not allowing him to enter the promised land because he chose to ignore Gods command to speak to the rock, striking it instead.
Yes, Moses displays his anger, frustration, and arrogance in this moment by equating his acts with God’s, but he was long forgiven for his sin with the Egyptian or he would not have been able to stand in God’s presence and live as he did on numerous occasions.

"both were sinful" - Can we be certain of this with the Egyptian? As the OP remarks, the text doesn't explicitly remark on this, and there's perhaps a sense of implied justice (the Egyptian Nakah an Israelite, so Moses Nakah the Egyptian). Could be worth adding an explanation for why the reader should consider Moses' act sinful.

@Stevecanhelp I certainly don't presume to stand in God's place on this. If it was nakah (smiting) and nakah it would certainly seems reciprocal, but I believe in this case its makkeh (beating) and wayyak (killing). Moses seems to think what he did was wrong "“What I did is certainly known.” at least by the lands standards. How much he knew of God and what God actually thought is indeed unknown!
